# ASPNET MVC: Retrieve Field Id in Javascript for non-Model fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 fields in a MVC view.
One is  @Html.**TextBox**("txtFirstName")
Second is hidden - @Html.**TextBoxFor**(model => model.FirstName, new { @type = "hidden" })

The hiddenField is there for posting purposes (as the firstTextbox can be disabled as times).

My question is How do I retrieve the client ID of first Textbox in Javascript ?? I can easily access the client ID of second textbox by '@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.FirstName)'

The client ID has the modelName prefixed and I dont want to do any hardcoding in Javascript code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it will be `txtFirstName`.

But you could explicitly set it:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtFirstName", "some sample value", new { id = "txtFirstName" })
```

and then access it as usual:

```
var value = document.getElementById('txtFirstName').value;
```

or if you are using jQuery:

```
var value = $('#txtFirstName').val();
```

Comment: It was ModelName_txtFirstName actually but as you mentioned setting it explicitly via object htmlAttributes works..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML helper inside your Javascript:

**Javascript & Razor:**

```
var textboxId = '@Html.IdFor(m => m.FirstName)';
```

There are several extensions:

```
@Html.IdFor(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.NameFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

Here is the full list of HTML helper methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper_methods(v=vs.108).aspx

Good luck